# mysql database output some confusing values

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, validation

[image]

I have a html form all the input fields having the attribute required. But in my database I'm getting some null values? And in some fields I got some confusing values like "5c6752e2954eb" this!

Comment: Please provide some output so we can analyze your problem. But I think this is on `data type` you set on table fields.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LGwN.png this is record snap.please help me!!!

Comment: What are you storing to your table? Integer or string? etc?

Comment: some fields are strings some of them are integers

Comment: Maybe you are inserting an incorrect data. Please doubleck it.

Comment: In my website stats hostgator says that there are 4 empty user agent string robot hits!i think the google is crawling my site using empty user agent strings.Thank you for kind help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is site is crawled by empty user agent strings! I think the google search is using empty user agent string robots to crawl the website. And the empty user agent string robots are ignoring the robot.txt file.We can block empty user agent string robots using .htaccess file using below code.

**insert this code into the .htaccess file**

```
hereRewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```